# What type of cylinder would roll down a slope faster; A solid cylinder or an inverted hollow cylinder?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, moment-of-inertia

I am conducting a lab right now in which I have been given a cylinder/can, which I can modify on the inside as I wish. The goal is to create a can that can roll down the fastest.

After some testing I settled on 2 shapes; a solid cylinder and an inverted hollow cylinder(**a hollow cylinder but instead the mass is concentrated in the centre rather than the outside**). The solid cylinder I have constructed by filing the can completely and the 2nd can I placed a stack of coins in the centre which I held in place with cardboard cutouts.

Whilst I was testing these two shapes, the inverted hollow cylinder was rolling down faster, which I found quite intriguing as I had thought the solid cylinder would be the fastest. I don't understand the reasoning behind as to why this is happening. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why under pure roll solid cylinder rolls down faster than hollow cylinder? Should they not be the same?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/586951/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two cylinders are of the same mass,
the cylinder with a more central mass-here being the “inverted hollow cylinder",would have a smaller moment of inertia and thus, a higher rotational speed.

It is this property that allows the “inverted hollow cylinder" to roll down faster.

This might be of help:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia